1990-2015 anime about three kids who found a portal in a lab and were transported to another world with different creatures
There were three kids, two boys and one girl. They found a portal in some lab and were transported to another world. They found different creatures there. The main creature was a yellow shark type monster. I was a kid when I watched it, so I don't remember much, but it was kinda like the show Digimon, except they could go back to the real world whenever they wanted and could bring the yellow monster the main character bonded with back with them. There were other monsters in the real world too, but no one could see them. Only people who went to the other world or monsters themselves could see each other.

Was the animation hand-drawn or computer-generated?

I can't remember

Is the answer below correct? If it is, please consider marking it as accepted by clicking on the grey check mark near the top-left corner of the answer. Or if the answer is incorrect, please leave a comment beneath it stating that, so that we know to keep looking.

Is this Invizimals (2013)...?
From the Invizimals Wiki:

What if I told you a scientist called Kenichi Nakamura had discovered invisible creatures living all around us? What if I told you he'd discovered a gate to travel from our world to theirs? And what if I told you we were embarking on a quest to unravel the mysteries of the Invizimals' world? Wanna join our team? Meet us after class. We are the Alliance of Invizimal Hunters, and we could really use your help.

A scientist named Kenichi Nakamura is studying mysterious creatures known as Invizimals. His laboratory contains a Stargate-like portal, through which he sends three kids -- two boys, Hiro and Sam, and a girl, Lima -- to another world to study Invizimals in their natural habitats.



In the first episode, the kids encounter an Invizimal named Tigershark, who -- as his name suggests -- looks like a hybrid of a tiger and a shark. Near the start of the second episode, Tigershark gives Hiro a crystal and tells him to use it if he's ever in peril.



